# UPDATE a column by COUNT of another table

Tags: mysql, performance, join, update, subquery, query-performance

It might be a naive question, but what is the difference of these two queries and which is preferred?

```
UPDATE table1, 
(SELECT id,COUNT(*) idcount FROM table2 GROUP BY id) AS B 
SET table1.Freq = B.idcount WHERE table1.id=B.id
```

and

```
UPDATE table1 A INNER JOIN 
(SELECT id,COUNT(*) idcount FROM table2 GROUP BY id) B USING (id) 
SET A.Freq = B.idcount
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same query. different join syntax.

The first is old style ANSI, the latter is later ANSI. If you must pick between them, pick the latter.

I wouldn't use either of them due to the limitations of USING (can't be aliased). Instead write as:

```
UPDATE table1 A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT id,COUNT(*) idcount FROM table2 GROUP BY id) as B
  ON B.id = A.id 
SET A.Freq = B.idcount
```

See this Oracle answer as to why `USING` is not to be preferred: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456684/mixing-using-and-on-in-oracle-ansi-join

And here is a similar discussion for SQL Server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax

In general, get used to writing SQL syntax in a way that is portable. While you may never port your code, you will at least be able to port your skills around to multiple database (Which is generally a cool thing to do to avoid becoming a one-trick pony).

Comment: You may want to add that `UPDATE` statements (and especially those involving joins) are quite difficult to be written in a portable way.

Comment: The join is ANSI-style, but the UPDATE as a whole is MySQL syntax. @ypercube Is it true that the only ANSI-compliant way to update one table from another is to use [subqueries in the SET clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855395/sqlite3-updating-a-table-with-data-from-another-table-only-if-4-other-columns-ma/18856225#18856225)? It's horribly verbose.

Comment: @IainElder I have to check but I think that in the latest standards, you can also update (with certain restrictions) a view, a derived table or a CTE, i.e.: `UPDATE (SELECT a.*, b.col2 FROM a JOIN b ON a.bid = b.bid) x SET col = col + col2;`